# Angular 5: Material table data not updating on triggering from a different component

Tags: angular, datatable, angular-material

I am working on Angular 5, I am facing an issue while updating the mat-table (Angular Material datatable).

There are 2 independent component (no parent-child) I am changing the value of a dropdown list in one component and trying to fetch the value from database based on that value and consequently updating the datatable.

While debugging I found that the updated data is coming from the database but I can't see any update in the datatable.

There could be some issue related to mat-table but not sure.

Thanks in advance.

Below is the code I am using to fetch the data from database and bind the datatable.

```
async GetFileHistoryDataBasedOnRole(selectedRole: string) {

    let fileHistoryDataBasedOnRole: any = await this.fileHistoryService.FetchFileHistoryDataBasedOnRole(selectedRole);

    if (fileHistoryDataBasedOnRole != undefined && fileHistoryDataBasedOnRole != null) {
      fileHistoryDataBasedOnRole = JSON.parse(fileHistoryDataBasedOnRole.toString());
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(fileHistoryDataBasedOnRole);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a minimal example for yourself:

Provide the data as an asynchronous stream that you can subscribe to for debug purpose. Each change of the filter, should re-trigger the subscribe block. If you have managed to get this working, the next step is to put this data into the dataSource.

The next thing to tackle is to ensure that a new object (array) is created when the datasource changes. As you can see in the example, if you just **push** data into the array, your table can never know that there was an update of the data.

Therefore, create a new array (**method add**) and extend it. This will re-render the table:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1erfob?file=app/table-basic-example.html

Comment: the piece of code posted above is being used for updating the data as well, the data is being subscribed successfully, I am getting the updated data from the db but it is not binding to the datatable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I have seen that example already if you will see in my code every time I am creating a new datasource object.

Comment: Yeah, but since the other code is missing I can't tell if it is really used or not. You can get better help if you extend the Stackblitz I used with your bug.

Comment: When I am triggering the same event with the help of a button instead of onchange event it's working perfectly but that is not happening with the dropdown change event.